# Rake assets:precompile on Heroku Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, precompile

I'm Using Flat-UI-Pro and the flatuipro.js file looks like this

```
//= require jquery.ui.touch-punch.min
//= require bootstrap-select
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require flatui-checkbox
//= require flatui-radio
//= require jquery.tagsinput
//= require jquery.placeholder
//= require jquery.stacktable
```

On localhost everything is working fine, but on Deployment to Heroku :

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.touch-punch.min'
```

What can i do ?

Comment: Hmm, i found the file, and the file is also in the app. I think this is such an easy task but i'm to new for this.

Comment: is it in the same dir as `application.js` and is named `jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js`?

Comment: The problem is only with this file? Try to remove it from application.js and run precompile task again. Maybe the problem is with your config.

Comment: I run flatui pro from a gem. And something happens with the pipeline (if i understood this correct). I moved every file in the JS folder, now it showing properly on heroku. Michael mind answering so i can upvote ?

Answer (score -1):

Run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add public/assets/
git commit -am "flatui assets to deploy"
git push origin master
```